# Is there a way to unsync contacts from Outlook that came from a particular source, specificly Dynamics CRM?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, address-book, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

So I installed the Dynamics CRM Client for Outlook and wired up a client's CRM to do some work for them. Unbeknownst to me, Microsoft decided to auto-opt-in the Contact sync to the Outlook Address Book. IE: All the contacts from the CRM's Contact entity have now synced into my primary Outlook Address Book. I now have over 35k contacts that I do **NOT** want in there.

Is there a way to "unsync" specific items from the Outlook Address Book that were synced from a particular source? Obviously, I only want those CRM contacts removed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simplest of solutions just don't come to mind. ;)

I added the "Created" column to the "Phone" View, sorted by that column, then deleted all the contacts created at that date.